# Using COUNTIFS to count blank when cell has a formula

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have criteria where I need to count if a column B is not blank. But I have a formula in Cell B, So if I do a simple

```
=Countifs(B1:B10,"<>")
```

This returns the count of the cells which have the formula but I just need the blanks when the formula does not populate anything.

Comment: So, the formula returns `""` for some values??

Comment: something like this: `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(B1:B6<>""))`?

Comment: @simoco your solution works great! but if I had to incorporate this into countifs function, it is possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this formula

[edited as per comments]

To count populated cells but not "" use

`=COUNTIF(B:B,"*?")`

That counts text values, for numbers

`=COUNT(B:B)`

If you have text and numbers combine the two

`=COUNTIF(B:B,"*?")+COUNT(B:B)`

or with SUMPRODUCT - the opposite of my original suggestion

`=SUMPRODUCT((B:B<>"")*(B:B<>0))`

Comment: this is going in a reverse counter. Say I have the formula from B1:B10. I copied your formula in cell C3. It display 10. Then whenever data comes in B1, cell C3 display 9

Comment: so you only want populated values, what sort of values? If they are text values try `=COUNTIF(B:B,"*?")` - that will count text values but not ""

Comment: say that B1 has the formula   =IF(A1="","",A1), Then it should count only when the formula return a value not when its blank

Comment: I know that you have "" values but I meant what are the values of the populated cells? There are various options depending on whether those are text, numbers or a combination - I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: True dates are numbers so you can use COUNT to count those - within a COUNTIF function use COUNTIFS(B:B,">0") - that should exclude blanks

Comment: RECOMMEND: `=SUMPRODUCT((B:B<>"")*(B:B<>0))`... I have used the `=COUNTIF(B:B,"*?")+COUNT(B:B)` approach in the past however this was not giving the correct result this time whereas `=SUMPRODUCT((B:B<>"")*(B:B<>0))` did  -- NB: This is possibly because some cells were a boolean (TRUE/FALSE) value.